# jQuery initialize Slider with data from JSON request (returned from php script)

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui-slider

at this moment i'm trying to initialize a jQuery Slider with data i've got from a PHP-SQL query encoded to JSON format.

PHP side is working, but i'm struggling with parsing the value (in the future there are more values to parse) to a variable and to push it as an initial value to the Slider.

Here are the functions and things i've done so far:

JS:

```
function schieber(){   

var handle = $("#custom-handle");

$("#slider-aktualisierungsrate").slider({
  min: 1,
  max: 60,        
  create: function() {
    handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
  },
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    handle.text( ui.value );
  }  
});}

function getSettings(){

var settings = [];

$.getJSON("/php/settings.php", function(data){

    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
       settings.push(parseInt(data.Aktualisierungsrate)); 
    });
    //settings = data;
    $("#slider-aktualisierungsrate").slider("value", settings[0]);
});}
```

This doesnt work, i call getSettings after Initializing the slider. Maybe there's a method to parse the JSON-Data inside the create-function of the slider.

Further I do not just want to initialize the slider, I want to push updated values back to the SQL database with another php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with this solution:

```
function schieber(){


var init = [];
var handle = $("#custom-handle");

$.getJSON("/php/settings.php", function(data){

    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
       init.push(parseInt(value.test)); 
    });

    $("#slider-aktualisierungsrate").slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 60,
      value: init,
      create: function() {
            handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );    
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        handle.text( ui.value );
      }  
    });

});}
```